# modal form embedded in html does not work in django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm making an application for food recipes and am trying to do the same html in the recipe and include comments in a modal window, the problem is that when I give I submit template fails and does not save the comment on the data base

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('recetas.apps.menus.views',
    url(r'^recetas/$','recetas_view',name='vista_recetas'),
    url(r'^reporte/$','reporte_receta',name='receta_reporte'),
    url(r'^receta/(?P<id_receta>\d+)$','detalle_receta', name='vista_detalle'),
)
```

The html code that calls this url

```
<td><a href='/receta/{{ receta.id }}'>{{ receta.titulo }}</a></td>
```

views.py

```
def detalle_receta(request, id_receta):
    dato = get_object_or_404(Receta, pk=id_receta)
    comentarios = Comentario.objects.filter(receta=dato)
    if request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('cancel', id_receta):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/receta/{0}'.format(id_receta))
        form = ComentarioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/receta/{0}'.format(id_receta))
    else:
        form = ComentarioForm(initial={'receta': id_receta})

    cxt = {'receta':dato,'comentarios':comentarios,'form':form}
    return render_to_response('menus/receta.html', cxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

receta.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block titulo %}{{ receta.titulo }}{% endblock titulo %}
{% block estatico %}
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/receta.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/modal.css' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function despliegaModal(valor) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("bgVentanaModal");
        elem.style.visibility = valor;
        }
</script>
{% endblock estatico %}
{% block contenido %}
<div id="bgVentanaModal">
    <div id="ventanaModal">
        <form action="/receta/{{ receta.id_receta }}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Grabar">
            <input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancelar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=receta>
    <div id="nombre_receta">
        <h1>{{receta.titulo|title}}</h1>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div id='ingredientes'>
        <h2>Ingredientes</h2>
        <p>{{ receta.ingredientes }}</p>
    </div>
    <div id='imagen'>
        <img src='{{MEDIA_URL}}{{receta.imagen}}' width="480" height="300" >
    </div>
    <div id='preparacion'>
        <h2>Preparación</h2>
        <p>{{ receta.preparacion }}</p>
    </div>
    <div id='comentarios'>
        <h2>Comentarios</h2>
        {% for item in comentarios %}
            <p>{{ item.texto}}</p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>Sin Comentarios registrados</p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="javascript:despliegaModal('visible');">Agregue su comentario</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div id="pie">
        <hr>
        <p>Receta Registrada el {{ receta.tiempo_registro|date:'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT' }} por {{ receta.usuario }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock contenido %}
```

everything works until I give the cancel key, does not validate the POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your `view.py`. Specifically in this part:

```
if request.POST.get('cancel', id_receta):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/receta/{0}'.format(id_receta))
```

That `if` will never result in a `False` value and, hence, your comment will never be saved. This has to do with how the [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function works:

> get(key[, default])
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

So, if you click `Grabar` you'll get the default value (`id_receta`). Try the following instead:

```
if request.POST.get('cancel'): # Default to None
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/receta/{0}'.format(id_receta))
```

A workaround would be just using a button with some JavaScript to redirect when you click `Cancelar` in your template:

**views.py**

```
def detalle_receta(request, id_receta):
    dato = get_object_or_404(Receta, pk=id_receta)
    comentarios = Comentario.objects.filter(receta=dato)
    if request.POST:
        # if request.POST.get('cancel', id_receta):
        #    return HttpResponseRedirect('/receta/{0}'.format(id_receta))
        form = ComentarioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/receta/{0}'.format(id_receta))
    else:
        form = ComentarioForm(initial={'receta': id_receta})

    cxt = {'receta':dato,'comentarios':comentarios,'form':form}
    return render_to_response('menus/receta.html', cxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**receta.html**

```
...
...
<form action="/receta/{{ receta.id_receta }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Grabar">
    <input type="button" value="Cancelar" onclick="window.location.href='/receta/{{ dato.id }}'"/>>
</form>
...
...
```

Of course, you should use [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) instead of hardcoding URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, The problem is that no entry in the post, it's like a page without form. when I push `Cancelar` or `Grabar` they back to page without the parameters `id` to show the recipe with the new commentary

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help me Cesar, your answer help me, but my error is in the variable in receta.html

is `{{ receta.id }}` and in the button is the same the correct is

```
<form action="/receta/{{ receta.id }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Grabar"/>
    <input type="button" value="Cancelar" onclick="window.location.href='/receta/{{ receta.id }}'"/>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help and a friend who found the error